# Docker container is running without port mapping

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I created a docker-compose file to build image from dockerfile and then run container this is my code:

Dockerfile

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java

VOLUME [ "/var/run/jars/" ]

ADD hello-world.jar /var/run/jars/

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "java" ]
CMD ["-?"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  hello-world-image:
   build: .
   image: hello-world-image    
  hello-world:
   image: hello-world-image
   container_name: hello-world
   ports:
    - "8080:8080"
   volumes:
     - ./logs_ACM:/root/logs_ACM
   command: -jar /var/run/jars/hello-world.jar
   restart: always
```

docker ps output:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                                  PORTS     NAMES
103b0a3c30e3   hello-world-image   "java -jar /var/run/…"   5 seconds ago   Restarting (1) Less than a second ago             hello-world
```

When i check running containers with "docker ps" the port column is empty therefore no port mapping was done even though i specified ports in my docker compose file.
What changes needed to be done on my docker-compose file to solve this issue ?

new version of dockerfile and docker-compose :

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/jars/

COPY spring-petclinic-2.4.2.jar /var/run/jars/

EXPOSE 8081

ENTRYPOINT [ "java" ]

CMD ["-?"]

version: '3'  # '3' means '3.0'
services:
spring-petclinic:
 build: .
# Only if you're planning to `docker-compose push`
# image: registry.example.com/name/hello-world-image:${TAG:-latest}
 ports:
  - "8081:8081"
 volumes:
 # A bind-mount directory to read out log files is a good use of
 # `volumes:`.  This does not require special setup in the Dockerfile.
  - ./logs_ACM:/root/logs_ACM
 command: -jar /var/run/jars/spring-petclinic-2.4.2.jar
mysql:
 image: mysql:5.7
 ports:
  - "3306:3306"
 environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
  - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
  - MYSQL_USER=petclinic
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=petclinic
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=petclinic
 volumes:
  - "./conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d:ro"
```

Comment: Your indentations look wrong. `container_name` should be indented to the same level as `image`.

Comment: the indentation is only wrong here when i copied it

Comment: There are a couple of odd constructions here (the `VOLUME` that's supposed to hold the code; the `ENTRYPOINT`; the separate Compose service that builds the image and runs `java -?`). Is the container actually running?  What's the actual `docker ps` output?

Comment: i updated my question with docker ps output

Comment: Your `docker ps` output shows `restarting`, which means it hasn't started successfully. Are you able to get it to an `Up` state?

Comment: What does `docker-compose logs hello-world` say?

Comment: @DannyB still showing restarting

Comment: @DavidMaze  "hello-world          | Error: Could not find or load main class java" apparently the problem is with jar i downloaded

Comment: Your problem is not in the port mapping, but in the fact that your container does not start. Viewing the logs or starting with a simpler "hello world" might put you on the right track.

Comment: yes i am using another jar for this container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your single biggest problem here is the `VOLUME` directive in the Dockerfile.  The [Dockerfile documentation for `VOLUME`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes) notes:

> **Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile:** If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.

So when you declare a `VOLUME` for the directory containing the jar file, and then try to `ADD` content to it, it gets lost.

In most practical cases you don't need a `VOLUME`.  You should be able to rewrite the Dockerfile to:

```sh
FROM anapsix/alpine-java

# Do not create a VOLUME.

# Generally prefer COPY to ADD.  Will create the target directory if needed.
COPY hello-world.jar /var/run/jars/

EXPOSE 8080

# Don't set an ENTRYPOINT just naming an interpreter.
# Do make the default container command be to run the application.
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/var/run/jars/hello-world.jar"]
```

In the `docker-compose.yml` file, you don't need a separate "service" just to build the image, and you shouldn't typically need to override `container_name:` (provided by Compose) or `command:` (from the Dockerfile).  This could be reduced to:

```yaml
version: '3.8'  # '3' means '3.0'
services:
  hello-world:
   build: .
   # Only if you're planning to `docker-compose push`
   # image: registry.example.com/name/hello-world-image:${TAG:-latest}
   ports:
     - "8080:8080"
   volumes:
     # A bind-mount directory to read out log files is a good use of
     # `volumes:`.  This does not require special setup in the Dockerfile.
     - ./logs_ACM:/root/logs_ACM
   # Don't enable auto-restart until you've debugged the start sequence
   # restart: always
```

Comment: i updated my question to include newer versions of my files .the two containers are up and running but i can't access my application on the browser " my_url:8080"